# How do I query for GCP ip resources logs by id?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, audit-logging

I need to find when and by whom a GCP ip resource was created by using audit logs. I found  the necessary parameters for some other resource form [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list), but I can't find information regarding querying ip logs(I already tried node_id). So how can I get the data I need with the information I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct filter string to get the creation event from logs.

```
"resource.type=\"gce_reserved_address\" AND resource.labels.reserved_address_id=\"$resourceId\" AND protoPayload.methodName=\"v1.compute.addresses.insert\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this documentation for Network queries that can minimize your search for IP logs. 
 
resource.type="gce_subnetwork" AND ip_in_net(jsonPayload.connection.dest_ip, "SUBNET_IP")

Comment: I assume this looks by ip, not the resource id